# Matplotlib mouse event not detecting any movement with the hist command

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to add a histogram of a random graph's nodes' degrees, and I have that displaying just fine. But I'm trying to make a new random graph appear when you click anywhere on the screen. I'm following the way to do it off of `matplotlib`'s documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) with some help from some other SO posts, but for some reason, the code isn't working.

Here is what I have:

```
import networkx as nx, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

def createGraph():
    # Generate random graph
    g = nx.gnp_random_graph(100,0.3)

    # Get the degrees of each node in the graph
    degrees = [degree for (node, degree) in g.degree()]

    ## create histogram
    count, bins, patches = plt.hist(degrees, edgecolor='black', normed=1, facecolor='red', alpha=0.75)

    ## Create the plot axes and labels
    plt.xlabel('Degree')
    plt.ylabel('Counts')
    plt.title("Histogram of Degrees:")
    plt.axis([min(degrees)-1, max(degrees)+1, 0, max(count)])
    plt.show()


def onclick(event):
    # Just any indication that something happened
    print("TOUCHED")


## program code
createGraph()
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

(This code requires the `networkx` library) but basically, all you need is a random list of numbers and replace the degrees list with that.

Comment: You call `plt.show()` within your `createGraph()` function, so *before* you actually connect the event handler to the figure. Remove `plt.show()` from that function and add it *after* the `cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect()` line. Then it will work as expected.

Comment: You show the plot before even creating the button_press_event. That is not useful. Inverse the order.